# Bug in Filling between ListPlots?

Tags: plotting, visualization, filling

I am trying to plot three data sets with `ListPlot` and fill the space in between the curves and axis, as indicated in the examples below. But a very strange thing is happening, which seems like it must be a bug.

Data:

```
test1 = {{0.4, 0.1425}, {0.425, 0.1204}, {0.45, 0.098}, {0.475, 
    0.0777}}; 
test2 = {{0.4, 0.1416}, {0.425, 0.1178}, {0.45, 0.0925}, {0.475, 
    0.0701}}; 
test3 = {{0.4, 0.1415}, {0.41, 0.1325}, {0.42, 0.1227}, {0.425, 
    0.1173}, {0.43, 0.1118},
   {0.44, 0.1008}, {0.45, 0.0905}, {0.46, 0.0807}};
```

Plot code:

```
ListPlot[{test1, test2, test3},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> Axis},
 Frame -> True,
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> All,
 PlotRange -> {{.42, .46}, {.08, .14}}]
```

Result:

[image]

When the vertical plot range is decreased a bit so as to "zoom in" on the problematic region, the issue goes away:

```
ListPlot[{test1, test2, test3},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> Axis},
 Frame -> True,
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> All,
 PlotRange -> {{.42, .46}, {.08, .13}}]
```

[image]

Can I fix this so that the image is drawn correctly (as in the second image above) regardless of my `PlotRange` settings?

Comment: Given the relative position of the plots you can just use `Filling -> Axis`; although, the filling colors will be somewhat darker for the bottom two due to the overlap.

Comment: Strangely, `Filling -> {2 -> {3}, 3 -> Axis}` and `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}` are both fine

Comment: Definitely seems like you stumbled on a bug! Note that even changing `0.1325` to `0.1324` in `test3` fixes it. Super weird. I'd report it to [wolfram support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).